# How to get a list of commits for specific user in any branch for several projects in git?

Tags: git

I work in multiple branches of several git projects. I would like to get a list of my commits for specific date, in all of these projects and branches (for timesheets purposes).

While I could write an utility script for that purpose, I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Is there an easy way to do this, using existing unix-based tools or some git power-user recipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For working with multiple repositories you could use [mr](http://joeyh.name/code/mr/).

Define a custom action in *.mrconfig*, like eg.

```
[DEFAULT]
git_daylog = git log --branches --after="$* 00:00" --before="$* 24:00" --author="$(git config user.email)"

[gitrepos/my_blog_app]

[path_to_another_project_from_home]

...
```

and you will be able to say `mr daylog 26 june` and get your logs for all the repositories registered with mr under your current directory.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! PS: I took a liberty to enhance your example of .mrconfig

Answer (score 10):

For a single repo:

```
git log --all --after="<date> 00:00" --before="<date> 23:59" --author="<author>"
```

`<date>` can be in any common format.  `<author>` is case sensitive, and also checks the email address.

#### Note:

This looks at the *committer* date (when was this commit applied to this repository/branch), not the author date (when was this content first committed).  This is important if you have rebased and/or cherry-picked.  There does not appear to be equivalent functionality for author date.

#### Edit:

To get this log for a set of repositories, you can run:

```
for dir in repo1 repo2 ... repo_n; do
    git --no-pager --git-dir="$dir/.git" log --all \
        --after="<date> 00:00" \
        --before="<date> 23:59" \
        --author="<author>"
      && echo  # to add a blank line between logs
done
```

Comment: For a script to get files by author date see accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37325709/281545