# How to get git to show commits in a specified date range for author date?

Tags: git, git-show

Apparently [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11189286/281545):

```
git log --all --after="<date> 00:00" --before="<date> 23:59" --author="<author>"
```

filters commits based on the *committer date*. How can I make it show commits for a specified author date range ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git log: filter by commit's author date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987273/git-log-filter-by-commits-author-date)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can't—at least, not in Git alone.  (Reminder to others visiting this question: it's not about *viewing* the author date, it's about *selecting commits by* the author date, a la `--since`/`--after` and `--until`/`--before`.  These selectors use the *committer* date, not the author date.  Consider as an extreme example a commit made "now", so that its committer date is in the 2000s, but backdated in the author-date field to some day in the year 1999.  If your selection range is "any time near the turn of the century" you'll de-select this commit, since its committer date is "now", more than a decade beyond 1999.)

I consider this a small bug in Git: you should be able to request that it use the author date field anywhere you can request that it use the committer date field.  This is easy with *log formatting*, since we have `%ad` and `%cd` and the like, but impossible with *commit selection*.  The closest we have is that `git rev-list` can sort by author-date (within general topo-sorting).

A global switch in `git rev-list`, like `--use-author-date`, would work as a simple patch, and would not be too hard to add to Git, but I think it would be better to have `--min-author-age` and `--max-author-age` or similar, and a "sort by author date" flag (independent of the general `--topo-order` flag, so that setting *both* flags has the same effect as `--author-date-order`).

As a workaround, you can list all potentially-interesting commits (with `git rev-list` or equivalent, such as `git log`: use whatever specifier makes commits potentially interesting, except for date filters: in this case that's just `--all`) and extract all of their author-date fields (with `git log --format=%at` or whatever), then do your own pruning of the list of commit IDs, then re-submit the remaining commit IDs to `git log --no-walk`.  But this is painful at best.  See [Tim Beigeleisen's answer using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37311841/1256452) for more.

Comment: Thanks for your authority clearing up the confusion for me - this has been bugging me for long and I did spend a lot of time going through the man pages to try and find the non existing switch. Is there a bug already open for this ?

Comment: I don't know if the Git folks consider this a bug.  See https://github.com/git/git for links to the mailing lists.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I also tried different ways and debug but not worked for me.

Comment: It is so sad that there is not such useful option to list by author date for a long time =(

Answer (score 181):

Maybe I'm missing something, but wouldn't this be enough?

```
git log --pretty=format:"%ad - %an: %s" --after="2016-01-31" --until="2017-03-10" --author="John Doe"
```

See also [here](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History)

Comment: @RossSolomon: that *shows* the author date, but *selects by* the committer date. To take an extreme example, suppose I make a commit with author date set to 1999 and committer date set to 01-01-2017. The `%ad` directive will show you this authored-in-1999 commit, even though that is way before 2016!

Comment: That command doesn't work with the iso-8601 date format in the --before and --after. The format that works for me is "dd-mm-ccyy".

Comment: Downvoting because this answer does not address the question, despite being useful in general.

Comment: Even if it does not answer the question, if I happened to stumble upon this answer and found a solution to my *similar-but-not-the-same* problem, I'm upvoting the answer, simple as that. However, this does not mean that the answer should be accepted, and I understand someone downvoting it.

Comment: I like to add --reverse to sort them from oldest to newest

Answer (score 46):

You **can**.

But as @torek mentioned, you might not be able to do this with pure Git.  One option would be to pipe some pretty format output from `git log` into `awk`, and check the author date there:

```
git log --date=iso --pretty=format:'%ad%x08%aN' | awk '$0 >= "2013-01-01" && $0 <= "2013-12-01"'
```

Here, the `%ad` gives the author date in ISO format, and `%aN` gives the author name.

Comment: Thanks - I went ahead and accepted Torek's answer as more comprehensive but upvoted yours for giving a starting point :)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it only works with one-line outputs. With `log -p`, for example, it won't do.

Comment: @SergeiTachenov Thanks for the comment, and I would suggest not moving to Houston.  NASA and the US are way past their peak, and the glory days of the Apollo era are probably not coming back.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, ha-ha! It's not like I have any chances of really moving there! And compared to Russian space industry I'm working at, pretty much _anything_ is state-of-the art, really.

Comment: Honestly, maybe have a look at the Chinese Space agency.  They just launched a space station, plus China is only a short plane ride from Russia.

Answer (score 8):

For those looking for a quick copy-and-paste solution:

```sh
git log --pretty='%aI %H' | \
    awk '$1 >= "<after-date>" && $1 <= "<before-date>" { print $2 }' | \
    git log --no-walk --stdin
```

Notes:

- The `<after-date>` or `<before-date>` portions can be left off as needed
- Dates must be in strict ISO format (`YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss` e.g. `2021-04-20T13:30:00`)
- Dates may be truncated, but similarly to `--after`/`--before`, they will always round down to an exact time.  Therefore, to find all commits on a particular day, for example, one of the following is required:

  - `$1 >= "2021-04-20T00:00:00" && $1 <= "2021-04-20T23:59:59"`
  - `$1 >= "2021-04-20" && $1 < "2021-04-21"` (notice `<` instead of `<=`)
- The date comparison does not take time zone into account.  If the repo has commits from different time zones and you need the precision, use your local time zone with `git log --date=iso-strict-local --pretty='%ad %H'`, or you can specify dates by unix timestamp and use `%at`.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37330563/8882017) by [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek), which was also contributed to by [Mr_and_Mrs_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281545/mr-and-mrs-d) and [Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen) (all involved on this question).

Answer (score 5):

inspired by Tim Biegeleisen's answer above.

`git log --all --date=iso --pretty=format:'%ad%x08%aN %s' | grep 2020-06-09 | sort -u`

did what I needed. I want author's date, not commits date because I rebase and squash a lot. but I keep important dates on import commits.

related to that, I have a small helper allowing me to reset the author's email but keeping the original author's date. --reset-author by default overwrites the author's date.

https://github.com/mathieujobin/git-scripts/blob/master/bin/git-reset-author-but-not-date

on the git log above, when needed, you can add `%H` to get the gitsha

Comment: %x08 in pretty format means ascii 08 which is backspace, so it eats the last digit of previous %ad which is author date in ISO format, so I use this variation (also added colon after author name) :
`git log --all --date=iso --pretty=format:'%ad - %aN : %s' | grep 2020-09 | sort -u`