# git since shows wrong information

Tags: git, grep

Using `git --since` and 8 days before, it returns commits in 20 days range

```
git log --all --author $USER --since "8 days ago" | grep "Date:"
Date:   Mon Dec 11 13:59:23 2017 +0300
Date:   Mon Nov 20 14:43:13 2017 +0000
Date:   Fri Dec 1 16:35:56 2017 +0300
Date:   Fri Dec 1 16:31:34 2017 +0300
Date:   Fri Dec 8 16:16:56 2017 +0300
Date:   Fri Dec 8 14:01:13 2017 +0300
Date:   Thu Dec 7 17:48:54 2017 +0300
Date:   Thu Dec 7 16:53:08 2017 +0300
Date:   Thu Dec 7 16:40:48 2017 +0300
Date:   Wed Dec 6 17:20:45 2017 +0300
Date:   Wed Dec 6 17:08:32 2017 +0300
Date:   Wed Dec 6 16:52:52 2017 +0300
Date:   Wed Dec 6 16:52:07 2017 +0300
Date:   Wed Dec 6 13:34:03 2017 +0300
Date:   Wed Dec 6 13:06:41 2017 +0300
Date:   Mon Dec 4 12:30:06 2017 +0300
```

Why it shows the second row (November), if today is the 11th of December?

[SOLUTION] According solution for this event, I need to use

[How to get git to show commits in a specified date range for author date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311494/how-to-get-git-to-show-commits-in-a-specified-date-range-for-author-date)

Thanks @torek for clarifying this

Comment: Your command seems to work for me without strange older dates in there...

Comment: so why then it show November in my case?

Comment: I mean I can not reproduce it so can't really help you.. Good luck though!

Comment: what is the output without `grep`?

Comment: Please check, whether `Date:   Mon Nov 20 14:43:13 2017 +0000` is really a commit date and not a part of some weird commit message. So remove `grep` part and inspect output carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each commit stores *two* dates: an "author date" and a "committer date".  The `--since` option selects or rejects commits based on committer date stamp, while `git log` *prints* the author date stamp by default.

Add `--pretty=fuller` (which prints both time stamps for each selected commit) and this should become clearer.

Comment: yeap, you were right. Interesting behavior
`AuthorDate: Mon Nov 20 14:43:13 2017 +0000
Commit:     XXX
CommitDate: Mon Dec 11 11:35:14 2017 +0300`.