# Git log --since=<seconds since epoch> misbehaves

Tags: git

I have a git repository with commits done by different authors that live in different timezones.

I want to see the history using `git log` since a particular point in time defined by seconds since epoch.

According to the image provided - it fails. What might be the problem?
[image: screen-shot of the command]

Comment: Does it work with `TZ=UTC git log --date=raw-local`? (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15103333/2679935))

Comment: I tried that, and the `--since=` parameter does not take into account that environment variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple separate problems here, not all of which I think you can solve using the Git front end commands alone.

First, each commit has *two* date/time stamps.  There is an *author date* field and a *committer date* field.  To see both, use `git log --format=fuller` for instance:

```
commit 5571d085b3c9c2aa9470a10bcf2b8518d3e4ec99
Merge: bedb914551 5cf8e06474
Author:     Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
AuthorDate: Wed Jul 18 12:20:35 2018 -0700
Commit:     Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
CommitDate: Wed Jul 18 12:20:35 2018 -0700
```

While the two are often exactly the same (as in this case), sometimes they are not:

```
commit 88a8ecaeaa87a84100c4eb49fb9af7a77977cc1b
Author:     Stefan Beller <sbeller google.com>
AuthorDate: Thu Jun 28 19:10:48 2018 -0700
Commit:     Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
CommitDate: Fri Jun 29 09:29:44 2018 -0700
```

The `--since` and `--until` operations work on the *committer date* but the default is to show the *author date*.  See my answer to [How to get git to show commits in a specified date range for author date?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37311494/1256452)  See also [Tim Beigeleisen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37311841/1256452), which shows how to use formatting directives to extract the particular date in a particular format suitable for use in awk or similar.

The remaining problem is the one you have identified: that time zone information is tricky.  Here, see [git: timezone and timestamp format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7651644/1256452) and note that the formatting directives `%ai` and `%ci` do not obey `--date=` but `%ad` and `%cd` do.  The `--date=` directives have expanded over time, so that as of Git 2.14, you can use `--date=local`, `--date=format-local:...`, and so on (and there are tests to make sure it all works).  See commit [6eced3ec5e5d7fbe61de2791e2627b1acf1246b3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6eced3ec5e5d7fbe61de2791e2627b1acf1246b3) in particular.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was that `--since=` was acting on the committer date and `git log` output defaults to author date. If one stumbles upon the output similar to that in my question, one can verify with `git cat-file -p <sha1>` that it is indeed the case.

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing on my own, and found that after setting the appropriate timezone, that the `--since=` parameter operates on UTC regardless of the Environment Variable `TZ` setting.

This is why you're seeing the second commit because UTC is +0000 and that second commit happened after your `--since` setting.

Normalizing the times to UTC (hope you like my ASCII Table):

```
              |    Given Time    |   in UTC
---------------------------------------------
--since=value | 1534762785 +0000 | 1534762785
commit c584d9 | 1534863946 +0600 | 1534869946
commit 4143b8 | 1534762784 +0200 | 1534764784
```

You can see that it's still correct, and both commits fall after your `--since` parameter.

Tested in git 2.14.1

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I do like your table, even though it is wrong - epoch times are always presented in UTC, hence your conversions are unnecessary. Anyway, I figured out the answer to my question already.